# How to approach debugging 404 on a route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

**What am I doing wrong in order to get a 404?**

I am issuing requests to my controller:

```
/// <category>Public Note operations</category>
/// <summary>   Gets the public note for the specified entity. </summary> 
/// <returns>   Note matching unique NoteId identifier. </returns>
/// <example>
///     Sample URI handled by this method is:
///     <code>
///       http://localhost:5001/ooo360/api/v2/Note(4a872b89-f42e-e511-9419-00155d104c97)/attachment
///     </code>
/// </example>
[Route("{entityLogicalName}/({entityGuid:guid})/PublicNotes", Name = "GetPublicNotesForEntity")]         
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Annotation> GetPublicNotesForEntity(string entityLogicalName, Guid entityGuid)
{
    // there's a breakpoint here that never even gets triggered
    return this._PublicNoteService.Get(entityLogicalName, entityGuid);
}
```

an example of a request would be:

> http://localhost:5001/ooo360/api/v2/TroubleTicket(058A9570-D373-E511-9420-00155D10416C)/PublicNotes

**What am I doing wrong?**

[image]

Comment: ~ Have you enabled attribute routing in the web api config? ~Shouldn't there be a `/` in between `TroubleTicket` and the Guid - http://localhost:5001/ooo360/api/v2/TroubleTicket/(058A9570-D373-E511-9420-00155D10416C)/PublicNotes ~ Do you have proper route prefix set up so that `ooo360/api/v2` will get resolved?

Comment: thank you very much for catching the idiotic mistake, missing slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of thing to be verified:

~ Have you enabled attribute routing in the web api config?

~Shouldn't there be a `/` in between `TroubleTicket` and the Guid - http://localhost:5001/ooo360/api/v2/TroubleTicket/(058A9570-D373-E511-9420-00155D10416C)/PublicNotes

~ Do you have proper route prefix set up so that `ooo360/api/v2` will get resolved?